# How can I list Celery tasks waiting in the routing queues?

Tags: python, redis, queue, celery

I use redis as the celery backend, and config different routing queues for the Celery app.

```
celery = Celery(
    main='MY_APP',
    config_source=config,
)
celery.conf.task_queues = tuple(
    kombuQueue(f'QUEUE_PREFIX.{task_name}', routing_key=f'QUEUE_PREFIX.{task_name}.#')
    for task_name in ['TA', 'TB', 'TC']
)
```

These queues are designated when tasks are sent.

```
my_task.apply_async(args, kwargs, task_id=my_task.task_id, queue=f"QUEUE_PREFIX.{my_task.task_name}")
```

When I use celery inspect to query `scheduled` and `reserved`, I can't find any tasks that waiting in above queues which I can query with the redis client.

My purpose is to find args and kwargs by task id and revoke this task, then send a new one with same args and updated kwargs. This a implemented in a standalone app so I coudn't know the task info directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's better you store task_ids(like database) and query them based on your input parameters whenever you want to revoke it. Celery has API to revoke already scheduled tasks [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#revoke-revoking-tasks)
. Its recommended to make your tasks idempodent to reduce the complexity of handling retries and failures.

If you still want to get the info directly from redis, internally serialised task messages are pushed onto a list and can be obtained by *lrange*. You can iterate through all the items, and remove the item which satisfies your query but this requires you to have good understanding of celery and redis. You can write a function in this way:

```
import json
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from itertools import repeat

import redis

def task_wise_counts(redis_con: redis.Redis, queue):
    task_counts = {}
    all_messages = redis_con.lrange(queue, 0, -1)
    for encoded_message in all_messages:
        message = json.loads(encoded_message.decode("utf-8"))
        if isinstance(message, dict):
            task_name = message.get("headers", {}).get("task")
            if task_name:
                task_counts[task_name] = task_counts.get(task_name, 0) + 1
    return (task_counts, len(all_messages))

def pending_tasks(redis_client: redis.StrictRedis, queues):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as pool:
        results = list(pool.map(task_wise_counts, repeat(redis_client),
                                queues))
    pending_tasks_data = {}
    for queue, (queue_task_count, total_count) in zip(queues, results):
        pending_tasks_data[queue] = {
            "total": total_count,
            "tasks_counts": queue_task_count
        }
    return pending_tasks_data
```